# Why is an answer that is so bad it is shown faded out kept around? Why not delete it?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

Looking at Stack Exchange websites, there are some answers with many down votes [like this one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22436/are-soldiers-overdiagnosed-with-ptsd-in-the-us-military/22442#22442) (just an example).

For what reasons for don't we delete / remove these kinds of answers?

Comment: The answer hasn't been deleted, it just indicates that the answer is inaccurate or incorrect as deemed by the community.

Comment: @Makoto I think OP is asking *why* it hasn't been deleted.

Comment: @Savanna That's correct. **Makoto:** I'm looking the **reasons** for don't remove them _i don't want put it in the OP, but this is a possible example_ (One of the reasons could be the quantity of comments on it).

Comment: @Mauricio Check this out. These are the ways answers can be deleted. If one of these conditions is not met the answer is not deleted http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: @Savanna Checked. You can add it as an answer for other viewers.

Comment: Please don't downvote this question.  This is a *request for information*, not a proposal to make a change.  We shouldn't downvote people on Meta just because they want to understand the site culture better.  (Think of the long-term effects of consistently doing that.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why *should* all downvoted answers be deleted?

A wrong answer, downvoted, also conveys information. It tells you, the visitor: *don't do this*. This answer is wrong, and if you are lucky the comments tell you *why* it is wrong.

If we deleted such answers, someone else might make the same mistake.

So instead, we (try to) only delete answers that are not answers (when they are new questions, or comments, or gibberish), or spam, or offensive, etc. We don't delete answers merely because they are incorrect.

Comment: _It tells you, the visitor: don't do this. This answer is wrong, and the comments tell you why it is wrong._ : It's a good point, but, how can be **visible** for the visitors?, maybe the key is hide them for "don't allow comments on it (if someone does)", maybe i'm exaggerating, but with @nicael's answer and yours can be the correct answer that i'm looking for.

Comment: @Mauricio: not sure what you are saying. The answer is not deleted, therefor it is visible to visitors. If downvoted to -3 or below, it'll be shown somewhat faded to further convey that the answer is not helpful or otherwise wrong, but you can still *read* it, and the comments on it.

Comment: I recognize that i'm a little confused, but as you noticed i marked your answer as the accepted one (would be nice if nicael's answer can be marked too _but i think that isn't possible_).

Answer (score 8):

Not all the downvoted answers are deleted. There is a reason to delete an answer, if it is:

- not an answer (it was posted as an answer, but should be a comment or edit, or something else (e.g. What things did you use and why didn't it work?) )
- link-only answer (because information, accessible from the link can become invalid due to server fault, etc)
- duplicate answer
- unproven answer
- very low quality (and cannot be improved by editing)
- it is spam (simply advertisement, promotion)

If it *does* provide an answer, even incorrect, it won't be deleted (unless it is full nonsense).